# How to make a Text and an Icon size-responsive in a Carousel Slider when it enlarges center page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, carousel, responsive

I'm using a Carousel Slider in Flutter with the enlargeCenterPage enabled as shown below. The carousel's items are a container including an image, some texts under it on the left and a "favorite" icon on the right. What I want to do is when the next page is coming to the center, as it enlarges, I want the text and icon to follow smoothly and enlarge themselves too. Then when I scroll and the page is leaving the center, text and icon follow again and smoothly become as small as previously. Is there any way I can do this?

https://files.fm/u/tt2xdvnr7 there is a video of what I want to achieve as asked from a comment below.

Here follows the code:

```
class MyCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCarousel({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyCarousel> createState() => _MyCarouselState();
}

class _MyCarouselState extends State<MyCarousel> {
  final controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
        carouselController: controller,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          aspectRatio: 1.6,
          autoPlay: true,
          autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 6),
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
        ),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) => _buildItem(index),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(int index){
    Item current_item = items[index];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9)),
        child: Container(
          width: 370,
          height: 200,
          color: LightPurple,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(current_item.image,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              height: 180,
              width: 370,),
          
              Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        current_item.name,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
              
                      AutoSizeText(
                        current_item.surname,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
              
                    ],
                  ),

                  // Here comes the icon with alignment "space.between" so it will go to the right
                ],
              ),
    
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Item is a class I made which has an image, name and a surname.

I have tried 1. Text widget, 2. Auto-Size-Text widget, 3. Text inside a Fitted Box Widget but did not work. Haven't tried something with the icon yet because i suppose it will be similar solution and i can't find for the text yet. What I expected was that the height of each page (of each container with the item) will change, and so will the texts. But then the texts remained the same, and if i made them a bit bigger they overflowed the containers ONLY THOSE THAT WERE NOT IN THE CENTER, because they were smaller.

Comment: Can you share some GIF to let us know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Akashgkrishnan just uploaded an MP4 hope it helps.